# VIM Adventures Level 9 - Getting out of the PI puzzle?

Tags: vim-adventures

[image: Cursor is sitting on the darkened "8" block.]

So, I'm playing VIM adventures to get a grasp on basic VIM.  In this case, the game is asking me to reach that key in the bottom right.  The cursor is currently sitting on the darkened "8" block.  I cannot move the cursor onto the numbers sitting over the bottomless pit.  Once a block is passed over, it disappears, which is how I ended up in this situation.

The game introduces various VIM keys over time- as of now, this is what I have available to me:
[image: Command :keyboard shows available keys.]

Essentially, I need to either find a set of keystrokes which would land the cursor on that block with the key or restart the game.  Restarting wouldn't be too much of a hassle, just good review if anything, but I figured someone here might enjoy looking for a solution.

Comment: What's' your question?  Are you asking us to play the game?

Comment: @Nelson        I'm just asking whether or not there would be a way, using VIM inputs, to solve this little puzzle. You don't need to play the game to understand, but you do need to understand VIM.

Answer (score -3):

I can imagine 2 possible solutions for now:
1. **
2. 10k l 7j 2l 4j 3l

Comment: I'm not sure why your answer got downvoted.  Solution #1 will not work -- on the first `*` Vim will try to find all the text in the "word" (so, **5058223172**), and since there's only one instance, the cursor will fall through the first non-blank character (5) and "die".  But, I've just confirmed that  Answer #2 works fine.  If you edit out the first (non-working) answer, I'll upvote.